# email confirm order not function

Tags: php, email, email-templates, ce-1.9.1.0

in my store magento 1.9.1 if buy a product not send email, but normal contact form function , i have follow this guide [New order email confirmation not being sent](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45571/new-order-email-confirmation-not-being-sent-magento-1-9-1)

and after this have solved for email confirm order

i changed the line

```
if ($this->hasQueue() && $this->getQueue() instanceof Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue) {
```

with this:

```
if (false /\*$this->hasQueue() && $this->getQueue() instanceof Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue\*/) {
```

after this have also test change :

```
if ($this->hasQueue() && $this->getQueue() instanceof Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue) {
```

with:

```
if (!($this->hasQueue() && $this->getQueue() instanceof Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue)) {
```

in every cicostance with this code solved my problem

but after changed this my cotact form not function , if click send compare new white page with this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '*', expecting identifier (T_STRING) in /home/lecolartga/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php on line 407
```

how solve this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this:

```
if (false /\*$this->hasQueue() && $this->getQueue() instanceof Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue\*/) {
```

with this:

```
if (false /*$this->hasQueue() && $this->getQueue() instanceof Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue*/) {
```

or just this:

```
if (false) {
```