# new order mail is not working

Tags: magento-1.9, email

New Order mail is not working while other mails like forgotten password,register are working.But new order mail is not working.I had installed "new order Email" free magento extension.Still it is not working.Can anyone help me how to achieve this task?

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/new-order-email.html

Comment: check this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45571/new-order-email-confirmation-not-being-sent-magento-1-9-1

Comment: You don't need an extension for this. This extension seems to re-invent core functionality, you should remove it.

Answer (score 0):

First go to **System > Configuration > Sales** Emails and make sure that **Enabled** is set to **Yes**.

After that look in **core_email_queue** table. If there are entries in the table and **customers/admin** are not getting any emails it means cron job is not running.

More details [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee1141-ce191-responsive-email#cron).