# Not receiving transactional emails in Magento 1.9.2.2

Tags: magento-1.9, email, transactional-mail, order-email

I am facing an issue in receiving email. I configured the **sales email** setting properly in Magento 1.9.2.0 and it was working good. But When I **upgraded** it to Magento **1.9.2.2** the emails are not being sent. I also checked the **Cron**, it is also set.

Is there any way to set it from admin panel? Or any way to get emails in my email box?

Comment: Check if you are using some custom variables in your emails in admin. Latest 1.x version requires you to white-list them first.

Comment: Can you share how you have setup your cron job. 1.9.2.2 doesn't support wget, if that's the case, as per my understanding.

Comment: I Made the following changes 

Generate Schedules Every     : 1
Schedule Ahead for                : 1
Missed if Not Run Within        : 15
History Cleanup Every            : 120
Success History Lifetime        : 120
Failure History Lifetime           : 120

Comment: Not this, the actual cron command you have setup in server's crontab.

Comment: No I didn't placed and command in the code

Comment: Yes, not in the code, but you would've setup some in site's control panel. Check cron jobs in there. You'll see one for magento's cron.php perhaps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New order email confirmation not being sent](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45571/new-order-email-confirmation-not-being-sent)

Answer (score 1):

After weeks of research and troubleshooting cron jobs in magento 1.9.2.2, i have finally found a solution from another forum. It worked without having to edit any coding.

From magento connect manager install ASCHRODER SMTP plugin and configure appropriately by going to;

System -> Configuration -> ASCHRODER EXTENSIONS -> SMTP -> Queue Configuration -> Queue Usage -> Never

Order Confirmation will be sent quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you really want to go around the cron setting and get emails by code-patching(which IMHO is not a good idea, but can be temporary patch), then you've to override Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template class as depicted here in the answer.

[New order email confirmation not being sent](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45571/new-order-email-confirmation-not-being-sent-magento-1-9-1)

Just put the class file in same path in `local` codepool(app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php), then open this file and find and comment out the `if` condition as below:

```
//if ($this->hasQueue() && $this->getQueue() instanceof Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue) {
            /** @var $emailQueue Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue */
            $emailQueue = $this->getQueue();
            $emailQueue->setMessageBody($text);
            $emailQueue->setMessageParameters(array(
                    'subject'           => $subject,
                    'return_path_email' => $returnPathEmail,
                    'is_plain'          => $this->isPlain(),
                    'from_email'        => $this->getSenderEmail(),
                    'from_name'         => $this->getSenderName(),
                    'reply_to'          => $this->getMail()->getReplyTo(),
                    'return_to'         => $this->getMail()->getReturnPath(),
                ))
                ->addRecipients($emails, $names, Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue::EMAIL_TYPE_TO)
                ->addRecipients($this->_bccEmails, array(), Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue::EMAIL_TYPE_BCC);
            $emailQueue->addMessageToQueue();

            return true;
  //      }
```

Then you can debug the cron setting and when you fix the cron then remove the file from `local` pool.

Hope this helps you out.