# Account confirmation email not working

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, email, customer-account, ce-1.9.2.0

I have email confirmation for customers enabled.

I am receiving emails on registration but after I click the email confirmation link, it directly redirects to login page and if I enter the login details I still says the account is not activated and check the email.

Edited:

This is the url which I am receiving in the hyperlink in "confirm account" email. Not sure if this is correct.

http://synergo.com.sg/sample/ergoshop/apple_sg/customer/account/confirm/?back_url=%3A%2F%2F%2Fcustomer%2Faccount%2Fconfirmation%2Femail%2Fbala%40mindlens.com.sg%2F%3FSID%3D9f0daf4310b7e778ba44c6785f3af7de&id=28&key=855732f3353ac274e7e6ab45c890a16a"

Comment: have you checked in admin side the customer confirmation or not?

Comment: @Bala, what is the version of Magento?

Comment: @Abdul admin side also not confirmed

Comment: @ArkadiyCh Running 1.9.2 (Stable)

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45571/new-order-email-confirmation-not-being-sent-magento-1-9-1. Just check this.

Comment: @virendra i am receiving emails, but clicking on the confirm email, the browser shows a path and then it automatically redirects to login page without verifying the email.

Answer (score 1):

I was using an extension to force the store to be seen only for the registered users. This had a redirect to login page with some exceptions to be whitlisted. I had to add the confirm url to the list to make it work.

https://github.com/jreinke/magento-require-login/issues/10