# Slow order confirmation?

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, email, cron

I have magento version 1.9.2.3 installed and the new order e-mail is delivered late for some unexpected reason. It takes 8-10 min to receive the order e-mail.

I've searched on forum but found nothing.

Anyone has the same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Magento 1.9.1, 'core_email_queue' is added to the database, emails are queued up here and sent via cron instead of directly being sent out. So you're seeing the emails go out when cron is executed.

More info http://jakesharp.co/magento/magento-emails-not-sent/

Comment: As your explained method i changed my cron setting to per 5 minute on my cpanel and now all of order notification received it right away.Tahnk you

Comment: No problem - I did some reading on the matter and it's to do with making the order confirmation page load quicker, as it may wait for the email to finish sending on 1.9.0.1 and lower before displaying the success page

Comment: My order confirmation emails take like 10 minutes to appear, any idea how I can make them send instantly?

Comment: @OliTuck you can change your cron intervals to something like 5 minutes, or install an SMTP email plugin which overrides Magento's default email queue. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45571/new-order-email-confirmation-not-being-sent-magento-1-9-1