# magento cron job not sending emails

Tags: magento-1.9, email, cron

i have a problem with cron job. the script is executed and doesn't return any errors but it doesn't proccess my queue either. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New order email confirmation not being sent (magento 1.9.1)](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45571/new-order-email-confirmation-not-being-sent-magento-1-9-1)

Answer (score 0):

it looks like that you have a problem with email server, because if the script is running without problems as you said, then only problem that you have is with sending mails.Are you able to send other mails from magento system,from command line or simple php script?
Without any other information I am afraid that I will not be able to help you.

Comment: i can send emails with simple php script and mail() so i guest the smtp is working

Comment: You can try to send mail programmatically thru Magento in the end of your script that is executed by cron job.Also you can try to send dummy maili in simple script to check is there a problem with Magento sending mails.If you able to share some code maybe we will be able to check for errors or something wrong, at the moment I am just guessing.

Answer (score -1):

Try to run cron.php in root direct manually & wait for 5 mins. This way

```
http://YOUR_SITE_BASE_URL/cron.php   (In browser)
```

If you get the emails then **cron setup is the issue**

else

Some other issue.

Comment: same result, the script is executing with no errors but the emails are not sent