# Magento order confirmation emails are not working

Tags: magento-1.9, email, order-email

The order confirmation email doesn't work. All other e-mails are sent. The cronjob is working properly, I checked in my database.

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Magento version 1.9.2.0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New order email confirmation not being sent (magento 1.9.1)](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45571/new-order-email-confirmation-not-being-sent-magento-1-9-1)

Comment: **This is not a duplicate!** The question is about a specific error message for order confirmation mails, the mail queue itself works.

Answer (score 1):

your order model seems to miss a method: https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1.9.2.0/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php#L1276

can you check the file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php in your installation for the queueNewOrderEmail method?

It's also possible, if you are using the compiler, that an old Version of the Class is compiled. So, if you have activated the compiler, you could try to recompile under System -> Tools -> compiler or deactivating the compiler.

The class that would be loaded by the compiler can be found here:

```
include/src/Mage_Sales_Model_Order.php
```

Another reason could be an opcode cache. To renew it the easiest way would be to restart the webserver

The File could also have been overloaded in one of these Locations:

```
app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php

app/code/community/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php

lib/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php
```

Comment: Hi David,
We got ahead. The problem is that the Controller cannot see (use) the queueNewOrderEmail class.
It is particularly strange because it can see (use) the sendNewOrderEmail next to the previous and both are public.

Comment: then it's even more likely that an old version of the class is loaded (due to the compiler or an opcode cache) since the method queueNewOrderEmail was added in the 1.9 version and the sendNewOrderEmail already existed before: https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1.8.1.0/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php#L1262

Comment: Is there sendNewOE in the 1.9.+ versions? Or is it unnecessary there?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I it may be still beeing used when actually sending the mail. the change in 1.9 was that the mails get queued and then afterwards sended asynchronously by a cronjob

Comment: actually, it's only a fallback and calls the queueNewOrderEmail Method: https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1.9.2.0/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php#L1369 still I'm thinking you should figure out why an old version of the class seems to be loaded

Comment: Do You have any idea whether why cannot Controller see the queueNewOE?

Comment: do you have a file <mage_root>/include/src/Mage_Sales_Model_Order.php? If not, another reason could be a file under app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php or app/code/community/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php which is outdated

Comment: We have this file and Order.php file is updated https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1.9.2.0/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php#L1276

Comment: which is "this" file. I just posted 3 locations where the Order Class can be overloaded. If at one of this places is an old Version of the Order Class, this one will be loaded

Comment: this one = app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php  the other one is is not existing among our files.

Comment: ah ok, does this file have the queueNewOrderEmail method? This file overloads the original File under app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php. Most likely there were made some customizations there to the order behaviour. Unfotunately this way of customizing Magento is a pretty safe  way to break Magento Updates. You could just delete this file, but this would revert any customization previously done

Comment: We use the original app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php without any costumization. Despite of it we can't reach the queueNewOrderEmail method.

Comment: you just said that there is a file under app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php if so, this one is used

Comment: This app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php is a full original file without any own code part.  In the app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php this method $order->queueNewOrderEmail() cannot go to queueNewOrderEmail.

Comment: the file under core does not make any difference as long as the file under local exists. The file under local will  be loaded and not the one under core.

Comment: Well we found an order.php file in the local path. It doesn't contain the queueNewOrder method. When we try to change for the original 1.9.x file it doesn't work at all. Nor we tried to put the queueNewOrder code part into this older file. In both case the process was stopped at paying method selecting.

Comment: ok so now you have another problem

Comment: Thanks David for your cooperation, you helped a lot to localize the issue, we solved the problem finally editing our older and newer files plus repairing our abstract php under checkout/model/type

Answer (score 0):

2 WAY to send mails from our magento store.

```
        Using cron AND  Avoid cron

if you DON'T WANT TO USE cron, follow this way:

GO your ->  order.php file At app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php

   FIND Line No: 1356,and 1450 (Change Code Both Line)

change  Code or Comment

FIND CODE ->  //$mailer->setQueue($emailQueue)->send(); 

to:

 Change:- $mailer-> send();


In app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/success.phtml

then add following line Top of success page for sending mail direct every Order:
```

####################Top of success.PHTML

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
$incrementId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId(); 
$order->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);

try{ $order->sendNewOrderEmail();} 
catch (Exception $ex) { echo "Email Not Sent..."; }
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
$email = $customer->getEmail();//End Email Sending
```

#######################Top of

success.PHTML###############################