# Transactional Emails are instant OR they are based on cron file?

Tags: email, cron, crontab, email-translation, email-scheduler

I have a magento website setup and development is also almost completed, but i am bit confused about `transactional emails.`

If a customer buy something from my webiste, does magento sends the email on `INSTANT BASES`. Or does it wait for the `cron to execute on its specified time`.?

I need this clarification before i hunt for something else.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Emails are not being sent directly during checkout but instead are being queued. The queue is being processed via your Magento cronjob

Comment: Thanx for the prompt reply @PrashantValanda i was confused in this thing only. 
Thanx for your support :-)

Comment: Just to note only the order confirmation email is queued - all other transactional emails like invoice/shipping confirmation are sent immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the latest magento version, magento has introduce new feature of processing the order confirmation email in a queue, so we must have to configure cron.php to call every 5 minutes in order to make this scheduled task work properly.

This cron.php file indirectly calls the cron.sh file which you will find in the webroot directory of your magento site.

More info [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45571/new-order-email-confirmation-not-being-sent-magento-1-9-1)