# Magento not sending email after upgrade

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, email, invoice

I updated my store from 1.9.0.1 to 1.9.2.4 and the order confirmation mail isn't working. I tried it manually by sending invoice through admin and it did work but it's not working on automatically. I even setup the cron but however, I think the cron is not working properly because the URL www.mysite.com/cron.php redirects me to 404 page not found.

And yes, I am testing all this on my test domain, my production website does send all the emails which is currently on 1.9.0.1
Any solutions?

Comment: Sales emails are sent via cronjob since 1.9.1, so you did not setup a cronjob on your test system. Duplicate: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45571/new-order-email-confirmation-not-being-sent-magento-1-9-1

Answer (score 0):

You can try and install AOE Scheduler extension. Then from the `System->Scheduler->Schedule Configuration` you can check if your cronjobs run (heartbeat).

If there is a heartbeat, check under `Timeline` menu if there are cronjobs scheduled ahead.