# Any type of email is not working accept forgot password in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-community

In my magento store any type of email is not send/working only if I do change user password from admin then it's send mail to particular user that your password is changed otherwise not any mail being send.

for double check that if php mail function is working or not I have create one **mail.php** file in my root directory and below is my **mail.php** code but this is also not working.

```
<?php
$msg = "test site mail for testing purpose";
$msg = wordwrap($msg,70);
mail("test@gmail.com","My subject",$msg);//test@gmail.com change with my email id
echo 'sent...';
?>
```

when I run this file siteurl/mail.php it's show me message **sent...** so it means it's pass through mail function but not sending mail.

above code doesn't send mail what does it mean? does php mail function is not configure with my server? if php mail function is not working then I change user's password from admin how it's send mail to user that you password is changed.

I checked but not able to find so I think let me ask to pro.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and discovered that my server was not running the cron. Magento 1.9.1 or greater insert all emails in a queue and uses cron to send it. Make sure your server is running the Magento cron:

```
/bin/sh /example.com/html/cron.sh
```

Also, [this post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45571/new-order-email-confirmation-not-being-sent-magento-1-9-1) has more details about it.