# How can i configure, If order placed by Cash On Delivery or Bank Deposit, customer get automatic order notification By Mail?

Tags: magento-1.9, email, transactional-mail

In my case, if order placed by `cash on delivery` or `bank deposit`, the **mail not automatically send to customer**, if i click to `send mail` from backend then only customer get mail.

Comment: so where's your question?

Comment: check my edited question

Comment: does customer get mail about new order by using

Comment: is other mails are working like `password reset or contact form` ?

Comment: yes, others working perfect, when customer placed order placed through cod or bank deposit order not send automatically, every time manually click "send mail"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New order email confirmation not being sent (magento 1.9.1)](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45571/new-order-email-confirmation-not-being-sent-magento-1-9-1)

Answer (score 1):

Since Magento ver 1.9.1 the order e-mails are scheduled to be send through the cron instead of directly. To enable cron for your Magento installation check: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job

Answer (score 0):

Transactional emails will send through CRON.
if you want to avoid cron, follow this way, it will help you.

```
//app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php Line#1356,1450 
  //$mailer->setQueue($emailQueue)->send(); Change To
```

```
      $mailer-&gt;send();
```

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/success.phtml
    //add following line Top success page for sending mail direct
    // Start Send Emai Here......
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
    $incrementId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId(); 
    $order->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);

```
try{ $order-&gt;sendNewOrderEmail();} 
catch (Exception $ex) { echo "Email Not Sent..."; }
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')-&gt;getCustomer();
$email = $customer-&gt;getEmail();//End Email Sending
```

Comment: make sure one thing, if i avoid cron, how email send ?

Comment: Hello @JeevaRathinam, Transactional emails will send through CRON.
if you want to avoid cron, follow this way, it will help you.

Comment: i typed this in answer. so, if u avoid this, every mail will go without cron permission.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 1.9.1 the emails are not being sent directly after order place. Email is stored in queue. The queue is being processed via your Magento cronjob - please ensure this has been set up and is running correctly.

There is two way to send order mail:

1.Using cron:

If you want your Transaction Emails to be sent through Cron, you can set the cron from from System > Configuration > System under tab Cron OR create cron in Cpanel direct it to your cron.sh or cron.php located in your root Magento directory.

2.Avoid cron: Transactional emails will be sent instantly.

Step 1: Go to `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php` at Line no: 1356,1450

There will be given below code:

```
$mailer->setQueue($emailQueue)->send();
```

Change this to:

```
$mailer->send();
```

Step 2: Go to `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/success.phtml`

Add following code at top of the success page for sending mail directly

Start Send Email Here......

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
$incrementId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId(); 
$order->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);

try{ $order->sendNewOrderEmail();} 
catch (Exception $ex) { echo "Email Not Sent..."; }
```