# Outlook email did not receive Magento transaction email

Tags: magento-1.9, email, transactional-mail, ce-1.9.3.0

My outlook email have not received any Magento transactional email yet (email order confirmation, new account). Our website using magento version 1.9.3.0. What do I need to configure or set else?

Comment: Hey Hana, welcome to Magento Stack Exchange. Turn on your logs and it will give you hints on what went wrong. Provided info is not enough to point out the exact issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New order email confirmation not being sent (magento 1.9.1)](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45571/new-order-email-confirmation-not-being-sent-magento-1-9-1)

Comment: I assume your server *can* send emails (that's usually not a problem) and you did not explicitly turn it off in *System > Configuration > System > Email* - then the most common reason for transactional mails not being sent is that you did not set up the Magento cron job yet. For details, see linked duplicate.