# Magento send order conformation mail not send to customer

Tags: magento-1.9

I try to place order in magento but **customer can't get mail**  and also **admin copy also not getting** how i fix this.

Comment: In admin mail you configure or not

Comment: Yes i set in backend

Comment: cron is working for you store?

Comment: Only this mail not working rest mail working

Comment: In Magento 1.9 order email email use queue. so you need to run cron. see here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45571/new-order-email-confirmation-not-being-sent-magento-1-9-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

add your root folder and then run if you get mail

```
<?php 
    ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    $from = "sendmailid&gmail.com";
    $to = "receivemail@gmail.com";
    $subject = "PHP Mail Test script";
    $message = "This is a test to check the PHP Mail functionality";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers);
    echo "Test email sent";
?>
```

**app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php**

find this `$mailer->setQueue($emailQueue)->send();` and change into `$mailer->send();`

**Note: Dont edit core file for testing only you try**

Comment: How to check this

Comment: in your root folder add this as mail.php then your browser www.domain.com/mail.php then check your mail you get mail or not