# Magento : Not Getting Order Email Notification

Tags: magento-1.9, email, order-email, notification

https://ramfootballshop.com/

I am not getting order email notification and Customer also not receiving mail when order completed. I tried all the ways. I dont know what should I do.

Simon

Comment: Have you setup proper cron? And have you confirm that you get other mail from magento like forgot password.

Comment: forgot password also not working...

Comment: Please check the screen shots,  https://ramfootballshop.com/corn.JPG
https://ramfootballshop.com/mail-notifications.JPG
https://ramfootballshop.com/sales-emails.JPG
https://ramfootballshop.com/store-emails.JPG

Comment: Please Check the following artical http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45571/new-order-email-confirmation-not-being-sent

Comment: I already tried this way...still not working...

Comment: Please set Disable Email communication option No.

Comment: Check your SMTP configuration has been done properly. Could you please check the Apache error log?

Answer (score 2):

Simon -

I took a look at your DNS settings; I might recommend adding in an SPF record to the server that gives the site authoritative permission to send email from this server.  I did check the server's IP address to see if it was blacklisted, and it looks clean / you're not blacklisted.

Transactional emails (placed after an order) require the Magento cron to run.  This was done to better enhance the performance, and not bog down a server during the checkout proess.

However, account signup - such as welcome emails - do not require you to use the cron - they are sent out right away.

I went through the system, and created a new account.  The good news is that the system is sending out the welcome email: [image: Welcome - Account Registration Email]

This lets me know that email is able to be sent through the site without a problem.

The logo on the email is broken however.

So... my best guess is that your cron for Magento is not set up properly right now.

One quick tip: if you re-enable the cron, you might want to clear out the table for past transactional emails.  Otherwise, everyone that has placed an order in the system will then receive their order alert emails.  That's fine if it's just a couple of days, but less good if you have orders stacked up in the system from many months.