# Invoice #100056169 | Paid | Apr 24, 2019 10:40:01 PM (the invoice email is not sent)

Tags: magento-1.7, invoice

Hello everyone can anyone able to help me,
my Magento store don't sending invoice email

Invoice #100056169 | Paid | Apr 24, 2019 10:40:01 PM (the invoice email is not sent)

Comment: In sales Emails = > Invoice Enable ?

Comment: All setting are complete also cron set proper

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New order email confirmation not being sent](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45571/new-order-email-confirmation-not-being-sent)

Comment: check your exception.log file (and perhaps the system.log file)

Comment: This can be located in the var/log directory. Also make sure that logging is enabled before doing so:

System > Configuration > Developer > Log Settings

That should at least point you in the right direction.